# Rendering JavaScript charts FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript') function displaying "fusion chart will load here" error

Tags: lotusscript

im writing a code tat ignore Flash and only use JavaScript for displaying fusion chart,i ve written this code in script library using lotusscript which will be called from agent.it is giving fusion chart will load here error

this is the following code

Print ||
    Print ||
    Print ||

```
Print |</head>|
Print | <body>| 
Print |<div id="chartcontainer">Fusion chart will load here!!!!!</div>|
Print | <script type="text/javascript">|
Print |FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');|
Print | var myChart = new FusionCharts("/+ dbCurrent.FilePath +"/Column3D.swf","12345","400","500","0","1","","noScale","EN");|
Print |myChart.setXMLData(sXML);|

Print |myChart.render("chartcontainer");|
Print |</script>|
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `FusionCharts.js` file is included in the `<head>` tag of your page.

You can read more about general debugging in the [FusionCharts Documentation](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?Debug/Basic.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the content type in your first print statement?
    print {content-type:text-html}